# equil height divs error(?) in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

this is driving me nuts...

I'm using the code below to make the text content area `.textContent` of a div the same height as the highest text content area of other divs. The goal is to have equal sized containing divs `.contentBlockShorter` all with an image that displays at the bottom, this will make more sense if you [visit the page](http://hhtoys.geoffmuskett.co.uk/products.php). It's the white blocks, the first one has the heading 'build your army'. On Chrome and ie9 everything is tickety-boo, but on FF and ie8 there is a gap between the text and image - I simply can't work out why! Can anyone see what might be going on? Thanks

**css**

```
.contentBlockShorter {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 1% 2em 1%;
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    min-width: 15em;
}   
.textContent {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
.contentBlockShorter img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="contentBlock contentBlockShorter">
    <div class="textContent">
        <h3>Build your army</h3>
        <h4><a href="#">battle packs and special sets to boost your army</a></h4>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div><!-- /textContent --> 
    <img src="img/horrible-histories-toys-roman-and-egyptian-battle-packs.jpg" alt="Horrible Histories Toys Battle Packs" />
    <br class="clear">
</div><!-- /contentBlock -->
```

**Javascript**

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$(".textContent").each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});
$(".textContent").height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: Looks same to me in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only don't get the white-space in ie, it's there in all other browsers.

I think it is to do with your font as you are loading in a font, the jquery is firing before the font is rendered, therefore it is using your fallback font (sans-serif) which is larger than the typekit font meaning when it finally gets rendered it will leave the white-space at the bottom.

To see what I mean, if you inspect the elements of your largest div and remove the "league-gothic" font of the headings, you will see that what remains fits the box perfectly.

You need to delay firing the jquery until after your font is rendered. Try using:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // javascript code here
});
```